How to display second author in poster template?
Hello everyone,
I'm having some difficulty getting two authors to show up in my poster.
Here is a minimum working example (MWE):
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1in,innermargin=-4.5in,blockverticalspace=-0.25in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in,paperheight=32.5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{uomtheme}

\usepackage{mwe} % for placeholder images

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
% \captionsetup[tabular]{position=bottom} %% or below

% set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{UoMTheme}
\usecolorstyle{UoMStyle}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{The title}
\author{Author1}
\institute{My University}
\author{Author2}
\institute{My other University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.07\textwidth]{mylogo.jpg}}

% begin document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{columns}
\end{columns}
\end{document}

The file uomtheme.sty file is below, courtesy of University of Wisconsin - Madison.
% UoM Theme for the tikzposter
% package.
%
% Author: Jiyu Chen
% Last Modified: 2019-05-21
%

% -- COLORS --


% UoM palette based on https://brand.wisc.edu/web/colors/
% and https://brandhub.unimelb.edu.au/guidelines/colour-palette



% UoM - Madison primary palette
\definecolor{UoMRed}{HTML}{c5050c}
\definecolor{UoMDarkRed}{HTML}{9b0000}
\definecolor{GreyBlue}{HTML}{dadfe1}
\definecolor{GreyDark}{HTML}{646569}
\definecolor{UoMLink}{HTML}{0479a8}

\definecolor{Yellow}{HTML}{f2a900} % Pantone 130
\definecolor{Gold}{HTML}{b58500} % Pantone 125
\definecolor{MetallicGold}{HTML}{8d702a} % Pantone 8640
\definecolor{UoMBlue}{HTML}{094183} % PANTONE 7687

% emory secondary palette
\definecolor{Cyan}{HTML}{00aeef} % Pantone Cyan
\definecolor{SkyBlue}{HTML}{41b6e6} % Pantone 298
\definecolor{Teal}{HTML}{487f84} % Pantone 5483
\definecolor{KellyGreen}{HTML}{348338} % Pantone 7740
\definecolor{SeaGreen}{HTML}{006c5b} % Pantone 568
\definecolor{Olive}{HTML}{5c8118} % Pantone 370
\definecolor{Orange}{HTML}{c35413} % Pantone 1595
\definecolor{Red}{HTML}{da291c} % Pantone 485
\definecolor{Magenta}{HTML}{c6007e} % Pantone 233
\definecolor{Purple}{HTML}{6558b1} % Pantone 2102
\definecolor{Grape}{HTML}{6d2077} % Pantone 259

% neutrals palette
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{101820} % Pantone Black 6
\definecolor{CoolGray5}{HTML}{b1b3b3} % Pantone Cool Gray 5
\definecolor{CoolGray2}{HTML}{d0d0ce} % Pantone Cool Gray 2
\definecolor{CoolGray1}{HTML}{d9d9d9} % Pantone Cool Gray 1

% web palette
\definecolor{LightYellow}{HTML}{ffde75}

% tikzposter color palette

\definecolorpalette{UoMPalette} {
    \definecolor{colorOne}{named}{UoMBlue}
    \definecolor{colorTwo}{named}{UoMBlue}
    \definecolor{colorThree}{named}{UoMBlue}
}

% tikzposter style
\definecolorstyle{UoMStyle} {
    \usecolorpalette{UoMPalette}
}{
    % background
    \colorlet{backgroundcolor}{white}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{white}
    % title colors
    \colorlet{titlefgcolor}{Black}
    \colorlet{titlebgcolor}{white}
    % block colors
    \colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{colorOne}
    \colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{white}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{white}
    \colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{Black}
    % innerblock colors
    \colorlet{innerblocktitlebgcolor}{white}
    \colorlet{innerblocktitlefgcolor}{Black}
    \colorlet{innerblockbodybgcolor}{colorTwo}
    \colorlet{innerblockbodyfgcolor}{Black}
    % note colors
    \colorlet{notefgcolor}{Black}
    \colorlet{notebgcolor}{colorTwo}
    \colorlet{noteframecolor}{colorTwo}
}

% -- STYLE --

% background
\definebackgroundstyle{UoMBackgroundStyle}{
    \draw[line width=0pt, color=framecolor, fill=backgroundcolor]
    (bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
}

% title
\definetitlestyle{UoMTitleStyle}{
    width=\textwidth, linewidth=5pt, titletotopverticalspace=0in
}{
    \begin{scope}[line width=\titlelinewidth,]
    \draw[color=colorThree,round cap-round cap]
    (\titleposleft,\titleposbottom)--(\titleposright,\titleposbottom);
    \end{scope}
}

% block
\defineblockstyle{UoMBlockStyle}{
    titlewidthscale=0.9, bodywidthscale=1, roundedcorners=5
}{
    \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blockbodybgcolor,
    rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blockbody.south west)
    rectangle (blockbody.north east);
    \ifBlockHasTitle
    \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor,
    rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
    rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
    \fi
}

% -- THEME -- 
% UoM theme
\definelayouttheme{UoMTheme}{
    \usecolorstyle[colorPalette=UoMPalette]{UoMStyle}
    \usebackgroundstyle{UoMBackgroundStyle}
    \usetitlestyle{UoMTitleStyle}
    \useblockstyle{UoMBlockStyle}
    \useinnerblockstyle{Default}
    \usenotestyle{Default}
}

% -- TITLE FORMAT --

% place logo to right of centered title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[anchor=south east,xshift=0.5\linewidth,inner sep=0pt] {%
       \@titlegraphic
    };
}
\makeatother

I would be grateful if someone could help me so that the first AND second author show up in the poster.  Ideally side-by-side. But for some reason it is only showing one author at a time.
Can someone help me understand why this is the case?  Thank you.

I didn't try it but the easiest is probably to put both authors together, i.e., \author{Author1, Author2} and \institute{My university, My other university}.

Thanks.  I'd like to add an exponent to the author's name, and a footnote explaining the author's affiliation.  How do I do that?

Assuming that you want the footnote to refer to the institutions inside \institution{} then it would be, again manually, \author{Author1\textsuperscript{a}, Author2\textsuperscript{b}} and \institution{\textsuperscript{a}First university, \textsuperscript{b}Second university}.
